# Unable to Retrieve Admin Password in GeoNetwork v2.5

Tags: geonetwork

I have just forgot the password of the geonetwork admin user.
There is no other accounts registred.

I have accessed the database successfully using MySQL workbench.
I tried to add a user through queries, but I didn't know the hashing algorithm that is being used.

Is there any way to create an account to access the admin console panel ?

Geonetwork 2.5 runing on Tomcat9, Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided here: [Gitter](https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#geonetwork_core-geonetwork:gitter.im)
By @endraceni:gitter.im

The Answer :
you can create users from admin console -> users and groups but since you don't have a user at all try using this insert statement

INSERT INTO users (id,isenabled,kind,lastlogindate,name,organisation,profile,authtype,nodeid,"password","security",surname,username) VALUES
(0,'n','',NULL,'nobody','',4,'','srv','','','nobody','nobody'),
(1,'y','','2024-02-28T16:02:47.895945Z','admin','',0,'','srv','46e44386069f7cf0d4f2a420b9a2383a612f316e2024b0fe84052b0b96c479a23e8a0be8b90fb8c2','','admin','admin');

and then login with credentials:
username -> admin
password -> admin